# Single word for "college projects"

Tags: word-request

I'm searching for a word that could be used to refer to projects that I created in the context of my academic studies.

Background: I'm working on my personal website and want to have a navigation menu item that links to a list of projects I created in college. I'm unhapy with the phrase "college projects", because I'd rather use only one word instead of two and because of the ambiguity of the word "college"; I'm studying at the University of Cologne, which AFAIK would be refered to as a *university* rather than a *college*, though I could never really wrap my head around the different meanings of both words.

So, is there a single word for that meaning? And if not, what (preferably short) phrase could I use to refer to that without said ambiguity?

First, I wanted to use the word "studies", but AFAIK that could also mean something entirely different, since "studying" not only refers to academic studies, but also to research or examination in generel; is that correct?

Comment: You could use "academic" projects instead.

Comment: Why are we helping you find a single word?

Comment: Because a single word looks better in a navigation menu. Also, I was wondering if there was any such word, since in general, most english words that refer to academic studies are very ambiguous (contrary to similar expressions in German). But as I said, if there is no such word, a phrase as short as possible is perfectly fine!

Comment: What is the German word you'd use?

Comment: Just curious, why do you feel the need to separate your portfolio by something as arbitrary as whether it was done for a professor or for a client?

Comment: @TRomano I'd just write "Studium". Or "Uni Projekte". Both options are clearer and shorter than English equivalents.

AffableGeek I'm still studying, so I want to seperate things that I did in an acedemic setting from things I did for fun or other motivation. There are many differences regarding conditions, scope and goal of the work, and I want to make clear why I did something and that there are associated reasons for some flaws in these projects.

Comment: @Jim Why don't you post that suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Classwork* refers to work done in class, as distinct from homework, work done outside of class for the class. But if your classes were "hands-on" labs, "classwork" might do. If not, "Work for Class" or "Class Work" would be succinct.

Comment: Does this term also refer to acedemic settings (in distinction from school work)?

Comment: By "academic" do you mean "college|university" as distinct from "secondary|high school" (German *Gymnasium*)? If so, yes; one can take college or university "classes".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you have created a portfolio. The purpose of your site is to promote your work to clients or employers. The work demonstrates your abilities. Portfolio often refers to artistic or creative work but this use is still a good fit. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/portfolio

Comment: Well, I have a portfolio page, but that is a collection of some stuff I made, not necessarily connected to my academic studies. I want to make clear that everything on that list was explicitly created in the context of a course at university.

Comment: How about coursework then?

Comment: To my understanding, coursework only refers to written works, doesn't it? I should mention that my academic projects include written assignments as well as short films and multimedia/website-projects